# GPO still applied from wrong server

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, group-policy, windows-sbs-2011

There are two servers in the network. The old SBS 2011 Server and a new Windows Server 2012 R2 Foundation Server. The group policies have been migrated to the new server. However, if I change gpo on the new Server, these changes are not applied to the users. It seems, as if the old server is still the one, from which the gpo are loaded.

How do I tackle this?

Update:

Both servers are in the same domain. The policies are on the top level.

[image]

Update 2:

The new server should replace the old one, but both servers are still running until everythings is migrated correctly. Unfortunately, I cannot recall how exactly I migrated the gpo.

Comment: An explanation for the downvote would be helpful...

Comment: I guess these two servers are in the same domain? if not, did you move your clients to the new domain? if they are in the same domain, where are your policies linked? on the top of the domain, on the OU where you have your work stations?

Answer (score 1):

There is a potential delay for propagation from the new DC to the old DC, and then (by default) up to a 2 hour delay before a workstation checks in and sees the new GPO. You must verify the GPO has propagated from the new DC to the old (I usually compare GPO version numbers on the status tab), then run `gpupdate` on the workstation to test immediately.

Comment: I don't think that this is the problem. The change was a few month ago an I ran several gpupdates on the clients.

Comment: You mention that you migrated the GPOs to the new server. How did you migrate them? Did the new Foundations server replace the old SBS server? If so, what was the process you used? Is the old SBS server still online?